# 'ToolTip' cannot have a logical or visual parent error while converting XAML to C# code

Tags: c#, xaml

In Our Application we do not use XAML,But C# code behind, So please help me to convert this XAML code into C#.

```
@"<Style TargetType='charting:LineDataPoint'>
    <Setter Property='Background' Value='Blue'/>
    <Setter Property='Width' Value='7' />
    <Setter Property='Height' Value='7' />
    <Setter Property='Template'>
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType='charting:LineDataPoint'>
          <Grid Opacity='1'>
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
              <StackPanel Margin='2,2,2,2'>
                <ContentControl Content='{Binding Path=Key}' ContentStringFormat='" + "Date" + @": {0:d}'/>
                <ContentControl Content='{Binding Path=Value}' ContentStringFormat='" + "Max." + @": {0:n}'/>
              </StackPanel>
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
          <Ellipse Opacity='1' StrokeThickness='1' Stroke='#FF686868' Fill='{TemplateBinding Background}'/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>";
```

Here the code I have tried, but when I run it, I get the error message "'ToolTip' cannot have a logical or visual parent."

```
var styleDataPoint = new Style(typeof(LineDataPoint));
var backGroundSetter = new Setter { Property = BackgroundProperty, Value = Brushes.Blue };
var widthSetter = new Setter { Property = WidthProperty, Value = 10.0 };
var heightSetter = new Setter { Property = HeightProperty, Value = 10.0 };
var dataPointTemplate = new Setter { Property = TemplateProperty };
var template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(LineDataPoint));

var gridElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
gridElementFactory.SetValue(NameProperty, "Root");
gridElementFactory.SetValue(OpacityProperty, 1.0);

var toolTiplElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ToolTip));

var stackPanelElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
stackPanelElementFactory.SetValue(MarginProperty, new Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2));
var tooltipLine = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentControl));
tooltipLine.SetValue(ContentStringFormatProperty, "Min." + @": {0:d}");
tooltipLine.SetBinding(ContentProperty, new Binding("Key"));
stackPanelElementFactory.AppendChild(tooltipLine);

var tooltipLine1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentControl));
tooltipLine1.SetValue(ContentStringFormatProperty, "Max." + @": {0:n}");
tooltipLine1.SetBinding(ContentProperty, new Binding("Value"));
stackPanelElementFactory.AppendChild(tooltipLine1);

toolTiplElementFactory.AppendChild(stackPanelElementFactory);

var ellipselElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Ellipse));
ellipselElementFactory.SetValue(OpacityProperty, 1.0);
ellipselElementFactory.SetValue(Shape.StrokeThicknessProperty, 1.0);
ellipselElementFactory.SetValue(Shape.FillProperty, Brushes.Blue);

gridElementFactory.AppendChild(toolTiplElementFactory);
gridElementFactory.AppendChild(ellipselElementFactory);

template.VisualTree = gridElementFactory;
dataPointTemplate.Value = template;

styleDataPoint.Setters.Add(backGroundSetter);
styleDataPoint.Setters.Add(widthSetter);
styleDataPoint.Setters.Add(heightSetter);
styleDataPoint.Setters.Add(dataPointTemplate);
```

Comment: Your application looks like it a WPF application, the simple answer to this question is, your application actually DOES use XAML if this is even something your looking to use.  More information is required otherwise this question cannot be answered as is.

Comment: By using things like stack panels, you are totally using WPF. It would be quite hard to make this work and still not use any XAML. IMO you'd have to come up with a really good reason not to use any XAML in a WPF application. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The codebase we maintain, is always instructed to use C# code behind instead of XAML.(Except exceptional cases). But this is the first time I got this type of error while doing the conversion task and it took long time and still not succeeded:(,Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced something similar not long ago, and I read (=realized) that you shouldn't build the visual tree by yourself as it were a normal DOM. Instead, you should use templating, that is using code (e.g. C#) to create a template, then apply it.

In other words, just follow the [FrameworkElementFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx)-way, despite is a deprecated API. I personally don't like relying on something is unsuggested, but it seems the best way to achieve what you need.

However, the "very best" way is using XAML!

Cheers